# List HTTP requests from android phone

Tags: android, http, url, proxy, request

What I want is to be able to see the HTTP requests my Galaxy S4 produces. I wanna build a web application and want to use the API that is used in some application. I know for sure that there is a HTTP request, and I want to capture as much as possible, but at the very least, the URL.

So far I've tried a couple of things:

1. `Look for Android apps that capture HTTP requests`. So far I have found some apps that can supposedly do the thing I need. But they all require root access, and I do not want to root my phone.
2. `Look for Windows applications that tether my wifi signal, which means every request is ported through my computer.` So far I've tried 1 application, `MyPublicWIFI`, and I tried using `netsh start hostednetwork`. The application didn't display any of the URLs, and right now it doesn't even share my wifi signal. The hostednetwork I tried to set up in CMD doesn't share the wifi connection (I enabled this option in the properties).

---

**I need a way to do this. Is there any way that I can get the URLs by porting the requests through my computer?**

Answer (score 13):

[Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) will allow you to do what you want. It is an HTTP proxy application that runs on Windows, OS X, and Linux.

You will need your phone and computer to be connected to the same LAN, and to adjust your phone's Wi-Fi settings to use a proxy, pointing it to your computer's IP address with port 8888. Then, all web traffic to/from your phone will travel via your computer and be visible in Charles.

You will be able to see the full details of any HTTP requests and responses (URL, headers, body etc.), the only limitation being encrypted traffic, but by installing the [Charles SSL certificate](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/) on your phone you can access this as well.

Since this is just an HTTP proxy, it doesn't require a rooted device.

The only downside I can see is that it is licensed software ($50US for a single user license), but the 'free trial' does not expire - the app simply closes after it's been open for 30 minutes, if I recall correctly.

For most devices (Android 4.0 upwards I'm guessing), the proxy can be set like this:

1. Go to Wi-Fi settings
2. Long press on desired network
3. Select 'Modify network'
4. Check 'show advanced options'
5. Set

   - Proxy: Manual
   - Proxy hostname: {your computer's IP address}
   - Proxy port: 8888
6. Save

Comment: Just to confirm. This still works in 2017. Thanks. This should be the accepted answer for its ease of use, and minimal setup.

Answer (score 10):

I finally figured it out, and got the API I was interested in. It is done in a few simple steps: *Tether your internet connection to your phone*, *Connect your phone to the newly created wireless ad-hoc network*, *make wireshark capture your requests*.

For tethering you have to set up a wireless network so your phone can connect to it. You do this using `CMD`, and view network connections in windows. You might also have to open the device manager for troubleshouting. I'll run you through it step by step

---

1- **Start CMD in Admin mode so that it has all the permissions that are needed. Then type the following code** (trying to start our hostednetwork):

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=networkname key=networkpass
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

if it works, move on to step 2. Otherwise, you'll have some troubleshooting to do. Sadly enough, there is not one easy way to do this. First view your *networkconnections*, and find your wifi, right click and disable it. Then go to *device manager*, head over to *network adapters*, and uninstall everything with *virtual* in it, these are virtual hosts, which make your CMD requests fail. You can enable your wifi again. Now wait a few minutes, and then try the first part again. If it still doesn't work, reboot your pc, and repeat this step. It seems like a hassle, and it is, but it's the only way i found out to do it.

2- **view your *network connections* and right click on it, choose properties. Now head over to the *sharing tab*, enable sharing your connection with others. Now look for wifi networks on your phone and select your network name and type your password.** (connect to internet with your phone):

You should be able to browse the internet with your phone now. If not, i do not know what to do. Try a browser first to check for your internet connection because some apps are blocked in this setting. This is for security reasons (you wouldn't want someone to raid your banking app).

3- **Download wireshark, install it, start capturing. Now make the requests you want to trace on your phone. Then stop capturing. You can now click on protocol, to arrange all the requests, you only have to check HTTP protocol. You can see the url on the right.** (checking the HTTP request)

---

**Summary:** We made our phone connect to the PC for using the internet. The PC makes all the requests to external servers and sends it results back to the phone. The requests made by the pc (thus both for the pc itself and the phone) can be viewed by wireshark.

Comment: you're gonna want to accept this answer so future users can check it out. This technically the same as what I answered but uses a different network topology, which is fine, you've explained thoroughly so no hard feelings.

Answer (score 2):

ACTUALLY . . .
using USB *reverse* tethering to provide network to phone and running wireshark on pc is probably the easiest way to do this.
See here:
http://foldingair.blogspot.ie/2013/11/debug-your-android-applications-by.html

- Disable mobile and wifi network on phone.
- Connect phone to pc on usb.
- Enable internet pass-though on pc.
- In phone network settings enable USB tethering.

I have added a seperate answer because I think this is the easiest and possibly most direct answer to this question. No need for rooting phone/router or installing proxies.

Please note I have not tried this (as I have combination of rooted prones or access to capture from network router) however it looks like a good method. Next time I find myself root/router-less I will be trying it out. Instructions for windows look easier than those for linux.

Comment: Good response, but i can't seem to connect my phone to my pc. The connection keeps stating that it is identifying stuff..

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest to use http://www.wireshark.org/ and/or http://www.tcpdump.org/ to capture packets either on phone (but need phone rooted) OR on point where your phone connects to network.

1. Capture using proxy
   Set up proxy as suggested in Answer "get a computer with two NICs" if you have PC with two NICs. Make the PC a proxy between internet and wireless that phone connects to. Run wireshark.
2. Capture on router
   You could also capture packets on wifi router directly. Have you control of router? Does router already have any logging/monitoring capabilities? Can you install openwrt and do packet capturing with tcpdump at that point? Probably about the same amount of work as is rooting the phone.
3. Capture on phone
   Rooted phones can run tcpdump. And with rooted phones you can also redirect requests by adding hosts entry in /etc/hosts or by making iptables rewrite ip addresses and/or ports.

Can you visit a friend's network where they already capture traffic and would allow you to take a capture file?

Either of the previous solutions are cleanest. You could maybe do something hacky with DNS server proxy and http proxy if you cannot root phone/router and don't have spare NIC and wireless router. I wouldn't recommend going to the trouble of doing this but I think it would be possible to:

- Install a DNS server. 
  Forward all requests on to a regular DNS server.
- Point phone at your DNS server.
  You should be able to see hosts which are looked up at your DNS server.
- Install a http proxy which logs and forwards http requests (perhaps apache)
- Make your DNS server forward requests you wish to intercept to your http proxy.
- Capture the URL on your http proxy

Comment: Charles Web Debugging Proxy suggested by Ellis looks good BUT I don't think there is a WiFi proxy setting on Android phone that you can change? Is there? I could well be wrong and would welcome being corrected. Thanks! (p.s. sorry I can't comment on other answer - no reputation :-P)

Comment: I see WiFi proxy settings in WiFi - long-click on connection - Modify - Advanced BUT will probably only work for browsers. "For each Wi-Fi network you add, you can connect via a proxy. Proxy settings are used by Chrome but may not be used by other apps." https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819519?hl=en

Comment: I have used Charles Proxy with a Galaxy S4 - it definitely proxies traffic from all apps (the reason I use it is to regression test another app). In fact, if the proxy is still set on the phone but Charles is not running, you will get 'unable to connect' messages. Also, yes, that's where you should be adding in the Wi-Fi proxy setting.

Comment: Thanks Ellis. That makes it very clear. I see those exact settings on my handset. Good to know you can set a proxy like that. You could also point it at a proxy you run on pc in your network and monitor urls at that point.

Comment: 'You could also point it at a proxy you run on pc in your network and monitor urls at that point' - isn't that what I'm suggesting when using Charles, though? Or are you talking about more of a hardware-based solution using dual NICs?

Comment: Nothing complicated :) just any proxy charles or other service on pc.

Comment: I like the idea of tcpdump and using hosts to redirect traffic (or show a login page or data usage warning). Fresh ideas!

Answer (score 0):

get a computer with two NIC's, set up the internet on one side and hook up a router's WAN (or just LAN) on the other if you do it right, enable internet connection sharing and use an application called wireshark. I assume that if you want to view HTTP requests, you're technical enough to set this up :)

this will help with HTTP, but not HTTPS.

for HTTPS you'll have to set up a transparent proxy and do some certificate manipulation, I've never successfully done that myself but i know it's possible.

Comment: @NickySmits Also, i just realised, you shouldn't have to have a computer with 2 NIC's, you can probably just set up the proxy server and set the phone to proxy using that computer on your network and wireshark it. However, the caveat is that I don't know (as somebody else pointed out) how strongly Android applications obey the proxy settings.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I found the solution and answered the question so other people can use it too. I did not have to set up a proxy on my phone, i connected to my pc, which made all the requests. It sounds like a proxy, but the phone recognizes it as a wireless network.